# How to get day value from date and show it in TextView?

Tags: android, datetime

I am getting date value from API as "date_display":"13/03/2018". Now how to display the date as 13 MAR 2018 and how to get the day value for this date and show it in TextView?

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //text.setText(result);
        try {

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONArray airlinesArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");
            for(int i = 0; i < airlinesArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject object = airlinesArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String id=object.getString("id");
                String rt=object.getString("route_type");
                String flightname=object.getString("flight_name");
                String fno=object.getString("flight_no");
                String dd=object.getString("date_display");
 HashMap<String, String> airliner = new HashMap<>();

                airliner.put("id",id);
                airliner.put("route_type",rt);
                airliner.put("flight_name",flightname);
                airliner.put("flight_no",fno);
                airliner.put("date_display",dd);
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, airlines,
                R.layout.details, new String[]{"flight_name", "flight_no",
                "date_display","time_display","display_route"}, new int[]{R.id.flightname,
                R.id.flightnum, R.id.date,R.id.time,R.id.route});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You just need to change dateformat

Comment: You can use `SimpleDateFormat` class to convert to desired date format.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM MM dd, yyyy h:mm a");
String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
view.setText(dateString);
```

you can get output like this

Fri Oct 26, 2018 4:55 PM

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for conversion :

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
Date date;
String result = "";
try {
    date = inputFormat.parse("set your date from API here");
    result = outputFormat.format(date);
} catch (e: ParseException) {
    Log.e("Error", "Parse exception", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` class to parse and  change date formats.

```
String dd=object.getString("date_display");

// Add these two lines
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dd);
dd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy").format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't know if you control the backend but you should send the time in milliseconds instead of a date. This way the UI can format the time in any way it wants.

Second, to answer your question, you need to parse the date given by the server. You are receiving a string so you need to convert it to a Date object. You can achieve this by using the **SimpleDateFormat**:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy ", Locale.getDefault());

try {
    Date date = format.parse(date);
    String day = (String) DateFormat.format("dd", date); // 20

} catch (ParseException e) {
    Logger.get().e(TAG, "getExpirationDate", "ParseException = " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

by using this method you can convert any date format to others

```
 String fromFormat="dd/MM/yyyy";
    String toFormat ="dd MMM yyyy";
    String date = "13/03/2018";

    public static String convertStringDate(String date, String fromFormat, String toFormat) {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
        Date d;
        try {
            d = df.parse(date);
            SimpleDateFormat dft = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat);
            return dft.format(d);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        }

        return null;
    }
```

> for more formats refer this link

[Date formats](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat)

Answer (score 0):

With `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
    String d = "\"date_display\":\"13/03/2018\"";

    d = d.replaceAll("\"", "").replaceAll("date_display:", "");

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(d, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    String newDate = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy")).toUpperCase();

    System.out.println(newDate);
```

prints

```
13 MAR 2018
```

and just the day to put in a `TextView`:

```
String day = String.valueOf(date.getDayOfMonth());
textview.setText(day);
```